# Download and execute update PHP

Tags: php, exec

I'm fully aware of  how sketchy this sounds, however to update some software on some of our servers, I wish to have a PHP file which will download and execute the exe. The exe requires no user intervention, and by double clicking it, it will in the background update all the required files. I so far have written the following code:

```
            <html>
            <font color=00FFFF>
            <b>Update.<b>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <b>Password:</b><br /><input type="password" name="pass" value="" align="center"><br />
            </form></center></html>
            <?
            $passkey = "OurPassword";
            if(isset($_POST['pass'])){
            file_put_contents("update.exe", file_get_contents("directdownloadURLToLatestBuild"));
            sleep(5);
            $r = shell_exec("update.exe");
            if($r==NULL){
                $s = exec("update.exe");
                    if($rr==NULL){
                    $t = system("update.exe");
                        if($t==NULL){
                        $u=exec(dir);
                    }
                }
            }
            var_dump($r);
            echo  "</br>^r";
            var_dump($s);
            echo  "</br>^s";
            var_dump($t);
            echo  "</br>^t";
            var_dump($u);
            }
            ?>
```

It downloads the file to the server fine, however it doesn't seem to be willing to execute it or at least it's having some issue with doing so. The VAR dumps all return with NULL but the last one which gives nothing of use whatsoever.
Could it be that it's trying to execute the file from the wrong directory? In which case that's annoying, as our servers have different dir structures for different branches. Or is there somethign deeper going on here?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Im not sure how this works on windoze, but you may want to try `passtrhu()` instead --- and your `.exe` does actually output something, right?

Comment: No, it shoudl just do it's thing. I was hoping to get any OS/Kernal error codes back from it with the dumping system i have going on there.

Comment: Oh, no, those variables would only hold the output of the script... i forget which is which, but one returns the last line of output, one returns all the output(if im not mistaken), and the other will flat echo it without allowing you to store the output to a variable....

Comment: Passthru didn't help either. So any idea why it might just be not executing the file at all?

Comment: hmm. Try adding this at the top: 
`ini_set("display_errors", "On"); error_reporting(-1);` - and see if you get anything useful from that...

Comment: No, it reports no errors. I did notice a bad check in my if statement, fixed that, and it's still not helped. :/ Do you know any way via PHP of checking permissions the user running the PHP script has?